# Fullcalendar: why is the calendar appearing twice on the page?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar for jQuery and for some reason the calendar is appearing twice on the page.  This is not a question about having two instances of fullcalendar on the same page.

Rather, at the bottom of the first calendar, there is a second identical calendar.

I confirmed that there is only one #calendar div in my page, so the error has something to do with my .js that calls fullcalendar.js, I believe.

Any help much appreciated.

JS Code:

```
jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({


        year: jQuery.today.getFullYear(),
        month: jQuery.today.getMonth(),
        date: jQuery.today.getDate(),
        theme: true,
        contentHeight: 1000,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                           // a lot of custom code
                    }
            });
```

HTML:

```
<table><tr><td valign="top" width="700px"><div id="calendar"></div></td></tr></table>
```

Other call of fullcalendar in javascript (this puts a datepicker in div to left of #calendar div on same page):

```
jQuery('#datepicker_for_calendar').datepicker({
          defaultDate: jQuery.today,
          minDate: jQuery.startDate,
          maxDate: jQuery.endDate,
          inline: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              var d = new Date(dateText);
              jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', d);
              selectedDate = d;
          }
      });
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant html and javascript?

Comment: I have quite a bit of code in the fullcalendar call, was hoping that there would be a generic reason.  Will try to cut down the code for the question.

Comment: it's quite possible that the "quite a bit of code" is part of the issue.  Also, what other `fullCalendar` calls do you have (with the string arguments for action)?

Comment: @justkt - I added above the code for the other call to fullcalendar, it is in a datepicker call for the same page.  I commented out all of the code in the dayClick but still have the double calendar issue. Also, when I click on a day in the datepicker, the first fullcalendar changes to that day as expected, but the second fullcalendar remains the on the same day that it opens with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a long week of bug testing everything, I found this jQuery plugin:

once()

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/once

Once applied to the #calendar div before .fullcalendar, problem solved, only one calendar rendered.

Working code:

```
jQuery('#calendar').once('calendar').fullCalendar({
```

...
})

Answer (score 3):

I was recently experiencing the same issue and tried the once() jQuery plugin, which didn't work for me. However, I re-downloaded the non-minified source and within the initialRender method I added the following line as the first line in the method and it resolved my duplicate calendar method.

`element.html('');`

My guess is my issue was coming from the fact that I was reinitializing the calendar on a drop down change without refreshing the page, which seems that the js code was constantly appending the calendar to the existing div without clearing out the existing calendar.

Answer (score 3):

Add `a.html('');` to function `f()` in the minified version.
I had mine open up in a dialog, every time I clicked a button to open there would be another calendar.
After a bit of reading, I found the method to use - `.fullCalendar('destroy')` - that way you do not need to edit the plugin.
Now, upon closing the dialog and re-opening, only one calendar appears.

Answer (score 0):

This should do this trick http://api.jquery.com/one.

So akin to @netefficacy (using **one** instead of **once**):

`$('#calendar').one('calendar').fullCalendar({...})`