# EmberJS view being rendered twice

Tags: ember.js, fullcalendar, ember-app-kit

New to ember and trying to figure out best practices.  Issue is fullCalendar is rendering two calendars when I switch to the calendar template.

Here is the console output:

```
Attempting transition to calendar ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #3: calendar: calling beforeModel hook ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #3: calendar: calling deserialize hook ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #3: calendar: calling afterModel hook ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #3: Resolved all models on destination route; finalizing transition. ember.js?         body=1:3499
Rendering calendar with <app@view:calendar::ember635> Object {fullName: "view:calendar"}         ember.js?body=1:3499
Transitioned into 'calendar' ember.js?body=1:3499
Transition #3: TRANSITION COMPLETE.
```

Here is my code:

*router.es6*

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'history'
});

Router.map(function() {
  //...
  this.route('calendar');
  //...
});

export default Router;
```

*routes/calendar.es6*

```
export default Ember.Route.extend();
```

*views/calendar.es6*

```
var CalendarView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
  }
});

export default CalendarView;
```

*templates/calendar.hbs*

```
{{#view "calendar"}}
  <nav>
    <h1>Schedule</h1>
  </nav>
  <article id="schedule">
    <section>
      <div id='calendar'></div>
    </section>
  </article>
{{/view}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question actually ended up being a repeat and was a fullCalendar thing apposed to an ember thing.  What worked for me was adding the jquery-once plugin and calling it like this

```
$('#calendar').once('calendar').fullCalendar();
```

SO reference: [Fullcalendar: why is the calendar appearing twice on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264681/fullcalendar-why-is-the-calendar-appearing-twice-on-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the didInsertElement hook on the view, try putting the following on your CalendarRoute:

```
model: function(){
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
    });
}
```

Comment: The right idea, just don't put it into Route#model. That same code could be in View#didInsertElement.

Comment: @Ember Sherpa: What's the significance of that position change?

Comment: cleaner code ? 'model' hook should be used to return the model needed for that route. If possible, avoid anything else in that hook.

Comment: Fair enough, though unless I'm mistaken, it should work just fine either way.  How you organize your code and which hooks you invoke is up to you (and I don't disagree with the choice to put it in didInsertElement instead)

Comment: Thanks for the help with best practices everyone.  This change to user Ember.run.scheduleOnce works, however it does not fix the double render problem.  Any ideas where to look or how to debug to see how this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more idiomatic solution. When you are using plugins you want to manually detach their event listeners from the DOM otherwise you will create memory leaks.

```
var CalendarView = Ember.View.extend({

  renderCalendar: function() {
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
      self.calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement'),

  removeCalendar: function() {
    // Detach any calendar events
    this.calendar = null;
    delete this.calendar;
  }.on('willDestroyElement')

});

export default CalendarView;
```